# Data type mismatch in criteria expression (vb.net, access)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am trying to take data from the database to the grid.  The condition is `SELECT * FROM entries WHERE edate='" & Me.dtpDate.Value.Date & "'"` But I am getting the error message Data type mismatch in criteria expression[image].  Please see the code below.  Also I have attached a screenshot of the error message.

```
    Private Sub dtpDate_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpDate.Leave
    'GetDayBookOpeningBalance()
    If Me.lblHeading1.Text <> "Daybook entry" Then
        Using MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = FrmCommonCodes.GetConnection(),
            MyAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE edate='" & Me.dtpDate.Value.Date & "'", MyConnection)
            'Format(Me.dtpDate.Value.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
            If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConnection.Open()
            Using MyDataSet As New DataSet
                MyAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "entries")
                Me.grdDayBook.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables("entries")
                Dim DataSetRowCount As Integer = MyDataSet.Tables("entries").Rows.Count
                If DataSetRowCount > 0 Then
                    SetGridProperty()
                Else
                    ShowBlankGrid()
                    FrmCommonCodes.MessageDataNotFound()
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Else
        ShowBlankGrid()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what could happen for not using parameterized queries. What is the datatype of the column edate in your table? And if it is not a string why you pass a string as value?

Comment: When you put ticks around a date in SQL it becomes text.  Use SQL Parameters to preserve the actual datatype.  There is also no need to create a DataAdapter and DataSet if you are just going to throw them away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what could happen for not using parameterized queries.
I bet that your column edate is a column of type Date/Time but you concatenate your  `Me.dtpDate.Value.Date` to the remainder of your sql string command.
This forces an automatic conversion from DateTime to String but the conversion is not as your database would like to see.

If you use a parameter there is no conversion and the database engine understand exactly what you are passing.

```
Dim sqlText = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE edate=@dt"
MyAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlText, MyConnection)
MyAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@dt", OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtpDate.Value.Date
....
```

Comment: Steve, Plutonix  its working now.. I seeks ur help in future also... thank you very much... (Y)